# How to aggregate documents by date with Elasticsearch with document IDs

Tags: date, group-by, elasticsearch

I have many documents in a single Elasticsearch index.

One document has a date field like this format : "2014-06-15"

I would like aggregate there documents by days

```
Result :
 '2014-06-14' :
   - doc1
   - doc2
   - doc3
 '2014-06-15' :
   - doc4
   - doc5
```

However, with Date Histogram Aggregator, the result is only a counter of document. How to get document ID ?

Date Histogram Aggregator is not to do that?